# How to receive data from server (server written by java, to HTML file)

Tags: java, javascript, html

So on HTML, I'm trying to use the 'String' that server sends.

the 'Server' will contain the plain json-formatted string

I know that because HTML itself is not a programming language but a mark-up language I need to use external as javascript or someother language.

This is server side code, i'm modifying a code from other service given to me to start with.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    HttpServer server;

    try {
        server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(8080), 0);

        server.createContext("/", new HttpHandler() {
            @Override
            public void handle(HttpExchange he) throws IOException {
                System.out.println("[HIT] "
                        + (new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd_HH:mm:ss")
                                .format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime())));
                if (he.getRequestMethod().equals("POST")) {
                    // read POST request body
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(he.getRequestBody()));

                    String queryStr = "";
                    String line;
                    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        queryStr += line;
                    }
                    System.out.println(queryStr);


                }
            }
        });

        server.setExecutor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool());

        server.start();

        System.out.println("HTTP Listening on port "
                + server.getAddress().getPort());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

What should I do for:

1. Send POST request on HTML, (I tried  but seems it doesn't work)
2. Send String data from server to client, (How to use Outputstream?)
3. Process that string data on HTML file?

currently on HTML I just put the sample data as

```
var asdf = {json contents}
```

Comment: To retrieve data through ajax, look at [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest). There is also a more friendly way of doing this by using the jQuery library, look at [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). For the server, I suggest you look either at [nodejs](http://nodejs.org/) or [ASP.NET WebApi 2](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api).

Answer (score 0):

If your data is not sensitive then you can do it using Ajax. You can make an ajax call to your server and get the response back.
$.ajax({
                url: "Your URL",
                dataType: "text/html",
                type: 'GET',
                success: "Resultant Page"
            });
You will get the response in data.
Then parse it and render on your html.

Comment: `$.ajax` is jquery, OP wants to know how to do it in plain javascript.

Comment: xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax_info.txt",true);
xmlhttp.send();

Comment: create an xmlhttp ajax request and send it.